# CentOS server failed to mount /sysroot: bad initramfs?

Tags: centos, boot, kvm, initramfs, xfs

Our VPS SSD host based on KVM has experienced crashes during the last months: I was given just two screenshots of logs from my collegues and no `journalctl` log at all. We have two other hosts but from VPS provider based on VMWare: those always run fine, the three hosts running on KVM always gave troubles, crashing up to 5 times per month.

My team restored the crashed machine just by putting back a snapshot of another machine with the same CentOS image; they used this procedure other times and of course (?) other crashes could occur again in future.

As you can see in the first screenshot, a corruption of in-memory data was detected: I was given these two screenshots and the task to replicate the error in order to understand what happened. With no logs it might be quite of a challenge.

I know it's hard to understand without logs, but I collected a few infos:

1. the crash occurred in not regular time intervals;
2. the logs show a timestamp of three seconds and a half after the boot;
3. this boot phase might involve initramfs.

I'm taking my best guess here: maybe someone installed something and rebooted the machine, and maybe `update-initramfs` went bad and corrupted something. Previous logs were lost; the VPS provider granted us their hardware is running fine and no instances of QEMU or KVM crashed...so, no idea what caused the file system corruption; it's useless to run `xfs_repair` if another crash will happen since all hosts share the same CentOS ISO.

I know this might seem a question belonging to ServerFault, but my question is more Linux related: **in general, and not related to my particular issue, what could compromise initramfs?**

Here's the screenshots:

[image: First screenshot log]

[image: Second screenshot log]

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

Once you are are in emergency mode run

> xfs_repair -L /dev/dm-0 && reboot

Log in and in a terminal run

> sudo xfs_fsr /dev/mapper/centos-root 
>   sudo xfs_fsr /dev/dm-0 
>   reboot

Not 100% sure what the issue is but all my centOS VMs regardless of version does this. I was working on this issue for a week.